# Nested SVG node creation in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'v just started playing with d3js and find it strange that I have to create multiple selectors for each element I want to link to the background data structure for example separate selectors such as one for overlay text and one for rectangles to make an annotated bar graph.

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(data)
.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr('y',function(d,i){return i*10;})
    .attr('height',10)
    .attr('width',function(d){return d.interestingValue})
    .fill('#00ff00');

svg.selectAll("text")
.data(data)
.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr('y',function(d,i){return i*10;})
    .fill('#0000ff')
    .text(function(d){return d.interestingValue});
```

Is there a more convenient way of combining these into a single selection and enter() chain that creates both the rects and the text elements?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a [G (group) element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#Groups). Use a single data-join to create the G elements, and then append your rect and text element. For example:

```
var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + i * 10 + ")"; });

g.append("rect")
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("width", function(d) { return d.interestingValue; });

g.append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.interestingValue; });
```

Comment: And it comes from the man himself! thanks for the response and a great library.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work for dynamic data updates unless I set data bindings on the sub-elements with .data(). With the above code, an update to the data bound to g re-drew the elements within the g using the originally bound data.

Comment: Right; binding data to parent elements doesn’t automatically propagate it to children. You need to perform one of the following in order to propagate data from parent to child: data, datum, select, append or insert. See also my tutorial on [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).