# Nested SVG selections in D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a list of n associative arrays.

`[{'path': 'somepath', 'relevant': [7, 8, 9]}, {'path': 'anotherpath', 'relevant': [9], ...}`

Within a large SVG, I want to: a) create rects ("buckets") whose dimensions are proportional to the lengths of their `'relevant'` sublists, and b) create rects ("pieces"), for each of the elements in the sublists, placed "inside" their respective buckets.

After reading Mike Bostock's response to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350553/nested-svg-node-creation-in-d3-js), I'm sure that I need to use group ("g") elements to group the pieces together. I can get the code below to produce the DOM tree that I want, but I'm stumped on how to code the `y` values of the pieces. At the point where I need the value, D3 is iterating over the subarrays. How can I get the index of the current subarray that I'm iterating over from inside it when `i` no longer points to the index within the larger array?

```
var piece_bukcets = svg.selectAll("g.piece_bucket")
                      .data(files)
                      .enter()
                      .append("g")
                      .attr("class", "piece_bucket")
                      .attr("id", function (d, i) { return ("piece_bucket" + i) })
                      .append("rect")
                      .attr("y", function (d, i) { return (i * 60) + 60; })
                      .attr("class", "bar")
                      .attr("x", 50)
                      .attr("width", function (d) { 
                        return 10 * d["relevant"].length;
                      })
                      .attr("height", 20)
                      .attr("fill", "red")
                      .attr("opacity", 0.2)

        var pieces = svg.selectAll("g.piece_bucket")
                        .selectAll("rect.piece")
                        .data( function (d) { return d["relevant"]; })
                        .enter()
                        .append("rect")
                        .attr("class", "piece")
                        .attr("id", function (d) { return ("piece" + d) })
                        .attr("y", ????)  // <<-- How do I get the y value of d's parent?
                        .attr("x", function (d, i) { return i * 10; })
                        .attr("height", 10)
                        .attr("width", 10)
                        .attr("fill", "black");
```

Is there a method on `d` available to find the index of the node it's currently inside? In this case, is there a method I can call on a "piece" to find the index of its parent "bucket"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the secret third argument to the function:

```
.attr("y", function(d, i, j) {
  // j is the i of the parent
  return (j * 60) + 60;
})
```

There's a simpler way however. You can simply translate the `g` element and everything you add to it will fall into place.

```
var piece_buckets = svg.selectAll("g.piece_bucket")
                  .data(files)
                  .enter()
                  .append("g")
                  .attr("class", "piece_bucket")
                  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                    return "translate(0," + ((i*60) + 60) + ")";
                  })
                  .attr("id", function (d, i) { return ("piece_bucket" + i) });
piece_buckets.append("rect")
                  .attr("class", "bar")
                  .attr("x", 50)
                  .attr("width", function (d) { 
                    return 10 * d["relevant"].length;
                  })
                  .attr("height", 20)
                  .attr("fill", "red")
                  .attr("opacity", 0.2);

var pieces = piece_buckets.selectAll("rect.piece")
                    .data(function (d) { return d["relevant"]; })
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "piece")
                    .attr("id", function (d) { return ("piece" + d); })
                    .attr("x", function (d, i) { return i * 10; })
                    .attr("height", 10)
                    .attr("width", 10)
                    .attr("fill", "black");
```