# In d3.js nested data joins, how do I access data from earlier joins?

Tags: d3.js, nested

I have created a d3.js page which displays a set of graph nodes with (x,y)-coordinates, but I'm using d3's pack layout WITHIN each outer node.

I have functioning code which generates this page, and it looks like this:

```
d3.json("knowledge.json", function(error, graphNodes) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);

  graphNodes.forEach( function (graphNode) {

    var innerNodes = pack.nodes(graphNode);

    svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(innerNodes, function(d) {return d.id})
      .enter().append("circle")
        .style("fill", function(d) {return color(d.depth);})
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx",  function(d) {return (d.x + graphNode.xOffset);}) 
        .attr("cy",  function(d) {return (d.y + graphNode.yOffset);})
        .attr("r",   function(d) {return d.r;});
  });
});
```

This works, but it's dissatisfying because I'm using JavaScript's .forEach rather than a data-driven approach with nested joins.  Here's a nested join example:

```
d3.json("knowledge.json", function(error, data) {
    if (error) return console.error(error);

    var groups = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(data)
      .enter().selectAll("circle")
        .data(function (d) { return pack.nodes(d); })
      .enter().append("circle")
        .style("fill", function(e) { return color(e.depth); })
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(e) {return e.x;})
        .attr("cy", function(e) {return e.y;})
        .attr("r", function(e) {return e.r;});
});
```

Notice that I use .data twice here, first on the outer graph, then on a pack generated from each node of the graph.  However, this does not take the xOffset and yOffset from the outer nodes into account.  How do I get at the first join's data from inside the second join?  Although scope makes the following impossible, I was hoping for syntax similar to this for the last three lines:

```
        .attr("cx", function(e) {return d.xOffset + e.x;})
        .attr("cy", function(e) {return d.yOffset + e.y;})
        .attr("r", function(e) {return e.r;});
```

Thank you for any insights you can share!

Comment: Use the secret third argument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275571/nested-svg-selections-in-d3

Comment: What Lars said PLUS, if the DOM nodes are nested and bound to data in a way that correspond's to the data's hierarchy, then you can e.g. `.attr("cx", function(e) { var d = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum(); return d.xOffset + e.x;})`. Again, this assumes the parent DOM node is bound to the datum that's the `d` you're after.

Comment: Thanks, Lars and meetamit.  Those are both very helpful techniques to have!  Lars, I would up-vote your linked answer if I had enough reputation to do so.  Sorry.